# Congruencies for Fibonacci numbers

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences, fibonacci-numbers

I am trying to proof read a paper from Zhi Hong Sun, however I cannot reconcile several of the results.  I may have made an error, so I would like a confirmation from the community here.

Does the following theorem work for all positive integers $k$ and $n$?

> Let $k$ and $n$ be integers with $k\ne 0$. Let $F_n$ be a Fibonacci number, and let $L_n$ be a Lucas number.
>   Then
>     \begin{equation}F_{kn}/F_k \equiv \begin{cases}
>     (-1)^{km}(2m+1) &\pmod{5F_k^{2}}      & \quad \text{if } n=2m
> +1,\\
>     (-1)^{k(m-1)}mL_k &\pmod{5F_k^{2}}  & \quad \text{if } n=2m.
>   \end{cases}
> \end{equation}

Comment: I tried actually working out the alleged congruence, and it fails for all n, for at least one k>=1.  The errors grow with respect to n.  Some examples marked with asterisk: n=4 k=2 21=1 mod 5
*n=4 k=2 21=6 mod 5

n=5 k=1 5=0 mod 5
*n=5 k=1 5=5 mod 5

Comment: It holds for $n=4$ and $k=2$! $F_{kn}/F_k=21$,  $ (-1)^{k(m-1)}(mL_k)=6$ and $21$ and $6$ are congruent modulo $5F_k^{2}=5$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the congruence hold for all integers $k,n\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $k\not=0$. Note that 
$$F_{k+j}=L_kF_j-(-1)^{k}F_{j-k}$$
(use induction with respect to $j$ and recall that $F_{-n}=(-1)^{n-1}F_n$).
Hence, by letting $j=nk$, we have that 
$$F_{(n+1)k}=F_{k+nk}=L_kF_{nk}-(-1)^{k}F_{(n-1)k}.$$
Now we can verify the congruence by induction with respect to $n$.

P.S. For $n=12$ and $k=3$, then $F_{kn}/F_k=7465176$,  $ (-1)^{k(m-1)}(mL_k)=-24$ and $7465176$ and $-24$ are congruent to $16$ modulo $5F_k^{2}=20$.

Comment: Can you be more specific though?  Does it work for all k and n?

Comment: I assume you mean $F_{\color{#C00}{-}n}=(-1)^{n-1}F_n$.

Comment: @robjohn Yes, thanks!

Comment: Ok, I must be doing something wrong.  For the following example I get: Let n=12, k=3, 7465176=-24 mod 20.  Can we work out this example so that I can understand what you mean better.

Comment: Ok I am confused about this notation now.  I thought these terms were supposed to be remainders, ie -24, with a dividend of F_nk/F_k, and divisor 5F_k^2.   So that 7465176/20 =373258, with a remainder of 16, not -24.  Thanks for the help and comments.

Comment: @primedivine The congruence says that  $7465176$ and $-24$ have the same remainder (which is $16$) when divided by $20$